# How can I stay organized when changing asset locations used by express.js server?

Tags: node.js, express, server

I have been learning express and everything seems to be clicking into place so I am trying now to concentrate on organization and keeping things clean and intuitive. I am wondering if there is a convention for storing where certain files are stored to be accessed by my server? The idea is for example I have a directory something like this:

```
root/
|--html
   |--html1.html
```

but I want to change the structure mid project to:

```
root/
|--assets
   |--html
      |--html1.html
```

Or for example as a site scales I decide to move my public directory to S3 or some other cloud storage instead.

Now I have to go back everywhere that sends that file and change the path or the entire middleware to send an s3 file.  My solution is this, and it works, but I am not sure if it is optimal or if there is a convention that might be better.

I can store everything in an asset module like this which has methods to return a file:

```
function getFile(path){
    return fs.readFileSync(path)
}

module.exports = {
    html1: getFile(`${__dirname}/html/html1.html`),
    html2: getFile(`${__dirname}/html/html2.html`,
    image1: getFile(`${__dirname}/image/image1.html`
}
```

and import it into my server as "assets" and use it like this:

```
app.get('/*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.send(assets.html1);
  });
```

Now if I want to change the path or even use an asset from s3 I can simply change the logic/function/path etc all in one place rather than going through all my routers manually etc.

Any feedback or guidance on where to look for more info is greatly appreciated!